# Make Animated Sprite follow cursor on Mousedown with Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

This is my first posted question, so be gentle lol. I am trying to make a little game that will display different animated sprites on a canvas element that is laid over a user's webcam feed. Right now I am just working with one sprite to get the functionality right. I only want the sprite to appear and follow the mouse when left-click is held down. Right now the sprite appears on mousedown and animates, but disappears if I move the mouse instead of following. I only want it to disappear on mouseup. I have looked all over for the answer, but haven't been able to find one. Here is the js I have:

```
'use strict';

const video = document.getElementById('video');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const errorMsgElement = document.querySelector('span#errorMsg');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height =window.innerHeight;

const constraints = {
//  audio: true,
 video: {
    //  width: 1280, height: 720
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    }

};

// Access webcam
async function init() {
 try {
     const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
     handleSuccess(stream);
 } catch (e) {
     errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `navigator.getUserMedia error:${e.toString()}`;
 }
}

// Success
function handleSuccess(stream) {
 window.stream = stream;
 video.srcObject = stream;
}

// Load init
init();

//Code for drawing sprite on Canvas
var image = new Image();
image.src = "Starsprite.png";

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let magic = false;

var spriteWidth = 187; 
var spriteHeight = 60; 

var rows = 1; 
var cols = 3; 

var width = spriteWidth/cols; 
var height = spriteHeight/rows; 

var curFrame = 0; 
var frameCount = 3; 

let x =0;
let y =0; 

var srcX=0; 
var srcY=0; 

function startPosition(e){
    magic =true;
    x =e.clientX;
    y =e.clientY;
   
}

function movePosition(e){
    
    ctx.clearRect(x,y,width,height);
    x =e.clientX;
    y =e.clientY;
}

function endPosition(){
    magic =false;
    ctx.clearRect(x,y,width,height);
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",movePosition);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endPosition);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",draw);


function updateFrame(){
    curFrame = ++curFrame % frameCount;                 
    srcX = curFrame * width;  
}


function draw(){
    if (!magic) return;
    ctx.clearRect(x,y,width,height);
    updateFrame();
    ctx.drawImage(image,srcX,srcY,width,height, x,y,width,height);
    console.log(x + ", " + y);
   
}


setInterval(draw,200);
```

The movePosition function does update the x & y coordinates, but the sprite doesn't show while the mouse is moving. I tried creating an event listener to run the draw function on mousemove, but it messes up the animation because it fires every time the browser updates the mouse position.  Any ideas on tackling this problem?

Comment: Hang on, was missing a curly brace. It should work now.

Comment: This is the sprite sheet I am using. https://github.com/atrossarello/atlantalegalliftoff/blob/master/Resources/Starsprite.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have worked some more on it and animated the movement instead of trying to call the function over again. I based this on instructions for animating keystroke inputs. It works fairly well, but if I move the mouse very quickly to a new position it doesn't follow it all the way.

```
//Code for drawing on Canvas
var image = new Image();
image.src = "Starsprite.png";

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let magic = false;

var spriteWidth = 187; 
var spriteHeight = 60; 

var rows = 1; 
var cols = 3; 

var width = spriteWidth/cols; 
var height = spriteHeight/rows; 

var curFrame = 0; 
var frameCount = 3; 

let x =0;
let y =0; 

let mousex =0;
let mousey =0;
var stillx =0;
var stilly =0;

var srcX=0; 
var srcY=0; 

var left =false;
var right =false;
var up = false;
var down = false;
var speed = 60;
var lift = 30;
var buffer = 100;


function startPosition(e){
    magic =true;
    x =e.clientX;
    y =e.clientY;
}

function moveDirection(e){
    
    stillx = x + buffer;
    stilly = y + buffer;
    mousex = e.clientX;
    mousey = e.clientY;

    if(mousex>stillx){
    left = false;
    right = true; 
    
}
    if(mousex<stillx){
    left = true;
    right = false; 
}
    if(mousey>stilly){
    down = true;
    up = false; 
}

    if(mousey<stilly){
        down = false;
        up = true; 
    }
    
}


function endPosition(){
    magic =false;
    ctx.clearRect(x,y,width,height);
}
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",moveDirection);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endPosition);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",draw);

function moveSprite(){
    if(right && x<canvas.width-width){
        x+=speed; 
        // x+=speed;
        right =false;
    }
    if(left && x>0){
        x-=speed; 
        left=false;
    }
    if(down && y<canvas.height-height){
        y+=lift; 
        down=false;
    }
    if(up && y>0){
        y-=lift; 
        up=false;
    }
}

function updateFrame(){
    curFrame = ++curFrame % frameCount;                 
    srcX = curFrame * width; 
    moveSprite();
   
}


function draw(){
    if (!magic) return;
    ctx.clearRect(x,y,width,height);
    updateFrame();
    ctx.drawImage(image,srcX,srcY,width,height, x,y,width,height);
    
   
}

setInterval(draw,200);
```

If anyone has a better solution please let me know!